# Gradle build is running for infinite time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have latest Android Studio 2.1.2 with updated SDK and Operating System is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I build my project than it starts building a gradle and it runs for infinite time. I have modified some basic settings like check an offline work and set `org.gradle.daemon=true` in gradle.properties file. I still can't figure out what is the main problem behind this.

Comment: which Operating system you are using ?

Comment: Ubantu 14.04 LTS @ArifNoumanKhan

Comment: i knew it it would be linux :(

Comment: What is your output in 'Gradle Console' ?

Comment: It shows Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]  @AntonMalmygin

Answer (score 4):

when ever you find gradle is stuck at first run for unlimited time 
you need these 2 commands

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

run it in terminal 
an keep it safe some where

**Update 1 :**

if you have tried these commands then try to close existing project 
remove .android .androidStudio settings .gradle from home and reopen your android studio make new project and wait it will for sure work 
i have faced same situation

Comment: are you sure ? both of them ?

Comment: Yes, Executed both of them one by one

Comment: @Kuls Is this the first time you run gradle?

Comment: i hate it when the gradle do these kinda thing in linux ... one time i reinstalled ubuntu due to dragle building was running for 2 days :|

Comment: Its works!! :) (Isn't necessary to delete .android and .androidStudio)